# QNetworkAccessManager not emitting finished signal with this code

Tags: qt

so i have been browsing the previous questions before about this issue, but i could not find a solution for my code.

```
cpp file of dialog
------------------------------------------------
#include "everesult.h"
#include "ui_everesult.h"

everesult::everesult(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui1(new Ui::everesult)
{
    ui1->setupUi(this);
}

everesult::~everesult()
{
    delete ui1;
}

void everesult::setmodel(QStandardItemModel *model)
{
    ui1->listView->setModel(model);
}

void everesult::on_buttonBox_clicked(QAbstractButton *button)
{
    EveReprocess M_;
    QModelIndex Selectedindex = ui1->listView->currentIndex();
    QModelIndex StationIdsindex = ui1->listView->model()->index(0, 1);

    int typeID = 0;
    int stationID = 0;
    stationID = ui1->listView->model()->data(StationIdsindex, Qt::DisplayRole).toInt();
    typeID = ui1->listView->model()->data(Selectedindex, Qt::DisplayRole).toInt();
    M_.GetMaterials(typeID, stationID);
}
--------------------------------------------------
Getmaterial and replyFinished from main window.
--------------------------------------------------

void EveReprocess::GetMaterials(int typeId, int stationid)
{
    //get typeid from material list
    this->modelMaterial = new QSqlQueryModel();
    modelMaterial->setQuery(QString("SELECT tm.quantity, tm.materialTypeID, t.typeName FROM invTypeMaterials tm INNER JOIN invTypes t ON t.TypeID = tm.materialTypeId WHERE tm.TypeID=%1 ").arg(typeId));
    if (!modelMaterial->query().exec())
        qDebug() << modelMaterial->query().lastError();

    //Set eve Central Url with typeids
    QUrl url = QUrl("http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?");
    QUrlQuery q;
    int numRows = modelMaterial->rowCount();
    for (int row = 0; row < numRows; ++row)
    {
        QModelIndex index = modelMaterial->index(row, 1);
        q.addQueryItem( QString("typeid"), QString::number(modelMaterial->data(index, Qt::DisplayRole).toInt()));
    }
    q.addQueryItem( QString("usesystem"), QString::number(stationid));

    //set created url and connect
    url.setQuery(q);
    qDebug() << url;    
    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply *)));
    manager->get(QNetworkRequest(url) );
}

void EveReprocess::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    qDebug() << "replyFinished called";
    if ( reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError ) {
        qDebug() << "Request failed, " << reply->errorString();
        emit replyFinished(false);
        return;
    }
    qDebug() << "Request succeeded";
    //process with xmlreader and get values
    processSearchResult( reply);
}
```

some of the code is here, i think it should be somewhere here, as the rest works fine.

this issue showed up after i use a dialog to let user pick a int from a list.

below is the function that calls the dialog that i have made for this. sorry about code format wil clean it up after it is working

```
void EveReprocess::Search_TypeId(QString ItemName, QString SystemName)
{    
    QList<int> TypeIdList;
    QList<int> StationIdList;
    modelIds = new QStandardItemModel(10,2,this);
    if !(db.isOpen()) return;

    this->queryItem = new QSqlQuery;
    queryItem->prepare("SELECT typeID FROM invTypes WHERE invTypes.typeName LIKE ? AND invTypes.groupID NOT IN (268,269,270)AND published= 1");
    ItemName.prepend("%");
    ItemName.append("%");
    queryItem->bindValue(0, ItemName);

    this->queryStation = new QSqlQuery;
    queryStation->prepare("SELECT solarSystemID FROM mapSolarSystems WHERE mapSolarSystems.solarSystemName LIKE ?");
    SystemName.prepend("%");
    SystemName.append("%");
    queryStation->bindValue(0, SystemName);

    if(!queryStation->exec() || !queryItem->exec() )
    {
        qDebug() << queryItem->lastError().text();
        qDebug() << queryItem->lastQuery();
        qDebug() << queryStation->lastError().text();
        qDebug() << queryStation->lastQuery();
    }

    while( queryStation->next())
    {
        StationIdList.append(queryStation->value(0).toInt());
    }

    while(queryItem->next())
    {
        TypeIdList.append(queryItem->value(0).toInt());
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < StationIdList.count(); ++i)
    {
        modelIds->setItem(i,1,new QStandardItem(QString::number(StationIdList.at(i))));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < TypeIdList.count(); ++i)
    {
        modelIds->setItem(i,0,new QStandardItem(QString::number(TypeIdList.at(i))));
    }


    //
    everesult Dialog;
    Dialog.setmodel(modelIds);
    Dialog.exec();
}
```

Comment: Please don't use pastebin. At least not the way you do it. Your paste expires in 6 days. After that your question here is useless for anybody else. SO is not a question answer service solely for you, but a repository of answers and questions for everybody.

Comment: understood i wil edit my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you proceed any further, some of your code is allows [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Even when it's not a security hole, it'll still lead to bugs. Instead of using string substitution in SQL queries, you should be using bindings.

Your problem is here:

```
everesult Dialog;
Dialog.setmodel(modelIds);
Dialog.exec();
```

The `exec()` is a blocking function - it blocks the main event loop until the dialog is dismissed. Thus the signals from the threaded network access manager never get delivered to your objects.

You should display the dialog box asynchronously, like so:

```
everesult * dialog = new everesult;
dialog->setModel(modelIds);
dialog->show();
connect(dialog, SIGNAL(accepted()), dialog, SLOT(deleteLater());
connect(dialog, SIGNAL(rejected()), dialog, SLOT(deleteLater());
```

Note that it's misleading to have type names starting with lower case and variable names starting with upper case. Qt's convention is the opposite, and it's useful to retain it unless you have a good reason to do otherwise.

**DO Parameter Binding in SQL Queries**

```
QSqlQuery query("SELECT .. WHERE tm.TypeID=:typeid");
query.bindValue(":typeid", typeId);
QSqlQueryModel model;
model.setQuery(query);
```

**DON'T DO String Substitution in SQL Queries**

```
setQuery(QString("SELECT ... WHERE tm.TypeID=%1 ").arg(typeId));
```

Comment: yeh i know for regular querys, but i cannot bind a value with QSqlQueryModel?

Comment: Sure you can, you just don't bind it on the model, you bind it on the query, and then set the query on the model, that's all. I've updated the answer to show that.

Comment: ok i changed my sql query, and the dialog but i stil dont get a finished signal emitted

Comment: Check if your `connect()` to the network access manager succeeds. You're also ignoring the other signals that the manager emits. Like, for example, `authenticationRequired`. To be sure, I'd connect also to the `destroyed` signal of the network access manager - so that you know it doesn't get deleted from prematurely (by your mistake, that is).

Comment: this code used to work before i added another template to my project. http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid=34&typeid=35&typeid=36&typeid=37&typeid=38&typeid=39&typeid=40&usesystem=30000142 is the request url, as you can see it is an xml file wich i want to parse wich happens after receiving the finished signal

Comment: Well, then why don't you show that "template", whatever it is? I mean, that's likely where the problem is!!

Comment: everesult.cpp is the file that i have added, its the dialog wich i have added through the qt add function the first code that i have pasted

Comment: after looking closely i saw i had the evereprocess structure not declared right. in the template i added. i accepted your answer thanks!